# como puedo hacer que cambie mas textos no solo dos

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, variables, innerhtml

tengo aqui las variables pero no se como poner el inerhtml

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
  function cambiarColor() {
            var c1 = "azul";
            var c2 = "morado";
            var c3 = "rojo";
            var c4 = "verde";
   clic.innerHTML=clic.innerHTML==c1?c2:c1;
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <p><h1 id="clic">...</h1></p>
  <button id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()">¡Cambiar!</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: quieres que aparezcan todos los valores de las variables al mismo tiempo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo:

- la funcion `math.random` devuelve un numero entre 0 y 1
- La funcion `Math.floor` redondea a un valor entero

Tu codigo quedaria asi:

```html
<html>  
<head>
    <script> 
      function cambiarColor() {
        //creamos un arreglo de colores
        let color = ["azul", "morado", "rojo","verde"];
        // creamos una variable entre 0 y el la longitud de arreglo
        // en este caso 0 a 3
        let random_color =Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
        // le asignamos y pintamos el clic la posicion resultante entre 0 y 3
        clic.innerHTML=color[random_color]; 
      } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body>
    <p><h1 id="clic">...</h1></p>

    <button id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()">
    ¡Cambiar!</button>
    
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de Bryro es correcta, ya que así al hacer click te cambiará a diferentes colores. Sin embargo, si quieres hacerlo de forma ordenada, mi solución te podría servir. He guardado los colores en un array ya que lo considero más práctico. Al hacer click, incremento el índice, hasta que llega al fin del array, entonces se resetea. Así cambias los colores de forma ordenada.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var i = 0;

    function cambiarColor() {
      var colores = ["azul", "morado", "rojo", "verde"];
      clic.innerHTML = clic.innerHTML = colores[i];
      i < colores.length - 1 ? i++ : i = 0;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="clic">...</h1>
  <button id="cambiar" onclick="cambiarColor()">¡Cambiar!</button>
</body>

</html>
```